# Need to get Computer name When stite hosted on IIS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

i would like to get the computer name when my site is hosted on iis server.

i will get the username when i running my site from local. here is my code.

```
 PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
 UserPrincipal userp = UserPrincipal.Current;
```

but when i publish my site on iis server i m not getting the system name

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the following code snippet.

```
System.Environment.MachineName
HttpContext.Current.Server.MachineName
System.Net.Dns.GetHostName() 
System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(Environment.MachineName).HostName
Dns.GetHostByName("LocalHost").HostName
```

Hope this helps

Comment: i working only in local when i upload my site on webserver it is nt working

Comment: did you try all the snippets I have shown you on your server ?

Comment: yes i have tried all snippets plz click on this link:http://mobileapi.jobseeders.com/index.aspx

Comment: Did you check you computer name manually in your server ? OnbuttonClick show the result of code snippet and concatenate the code snippet as string so that we can know which code snippet gives which value ...and we can figure out.

Comment: @user3462829 it shows the server name as **WIN-A5PDG7S1OQG**.Aren't your server name **WIN-A5PDG7S1OQG** ?

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

add this namespace:

> using System.Net;

then use this:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string IP = Request.UserHostName;
        string compName = DetermineCompName(IP);
        Response.Write(compName);
}

 public static string DetermineCompName(string IP)
    {
        IPAddress myIP = IPAddress.Parse(IP);
        IPHostEntry GetIPHost = Dns.GetHostEntry(myIP);
        List<string> compName = GetIPHost.HostName.ToString().Split('.').ToList();
        return compName.First();
    }
```

Comment: it is also not working plz check this link:http://mobileapi.jobseeders.com/index.aspx
press second button

Comment: set breakpoints use debugger then inspect and  tell me value of 'myIP'

Comment: not working plz click on link:mobileapi.jobseeders.com/index.aspx press second button